# ¿Cómo mostrar mis eventos desde la base de datos con fullcalendar?

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema estoy haciendo una agenda con `fullcalendar` el problema es que a la hora de obtener mis registros de la `base de datos` no se muestran en mi `calendario` pero si obtengo mis resultados en consola:

`código` para generar el `plugin` de `fullcalendar` pagina `recordatorios.php`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid','interaction' ],
          //cambiar el idioma
          locale:'es',

          //eventLimit:true,
          events:'scripts/lista_recordatorios.php',

        });
        calendar.render();
      });
```

`código` para obtener mis eventos desde la `base de datos` pagina `lista_recordatorios.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=controldeflotilla;","root","");
$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT  * FROM recordatorios");
$query->execute();

$resultado=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Sí ejecuto esa pagina de `lista_recordatorios.php` me obtiene lo siguiente por lo que si esta funcionando el extraer los datos de la `BD` pero no se muestran en el `calendario`:

```
[{"id_recordatorio":"1","actividad":"prueba","descripcion":"hola mundo","fecha_inicio":"2019-07-15","fecha_final":"2019-07-16"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eventSource:**

Lo que intentabas hacer no se hace con `events` sino que se hace con `eventSources` ejemplo:

```
eventSources: [
    '/feed1.php',
    '/feed2.php'
]
```

Más información en la [Documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources) oficial

> La función `events` es utilizada para insertar los eventos a mano como así:
>
> ```
> events:[{
>   title: 'string',
>   start: 'date',
>   end: 'date' //Opcional
> },{
>   title: 'string',
>   start: 'date',
>   end: 'date' //Opcional
> }]
> ```
>
> Si quieres buscar más información en la [Documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array) oficial

Comment: ok ya lo cambie como me indicas pero aun así no aparece nada en el calendario que me podría estar faltando ??

Comment: Puede que necesites estructurar de la misma forma el array ```[{title:'df',start:'date',end:'date'}]```

Comment: Y si eso no te funciona te recomiendo el hacer un foreach sobre la información y mostrarla directamente

Comment: hice un foreach mas la estructura de fullcalendar y funciono perfectamente gracias por tu sugerencia